# Using jquery split the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to split one  into 2 separate 's using jquery (div could be dynamically generated)

This is the current code i am working with

```
$(function() {
     $("#" + gend).click(function(e) {

        $("#" + gend).mousemove(function(event) {

                 alert("mousemove"+gend);
                 var x_begin =event.pageX;
                 var y_begin = event.pageY;
                 console.log("mouddd"+y_begin);

                 delay(function(){
                      console.log("dragsss"+y_begin);
                      splitDiv(gend,x_begin,y_begin);
                    }, 100);
                 });

                 var delay = (function(){
                 var timer = 0;
                 return function(callback, ms){
                     clearTimeout (timer);
                     timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
            };
        })();
```

Comment: And what is your html code?

Comment: I modified the code please check it

Comment: Where is `gend` defined?

Comment: It will be good to find what you want if you add a fiddle.

Comment: gend (box) was dynamically created based on coordinate values.I want to seprate this gend into 2

Comment: please provide your code in jsfiddle.